# How to configure django-allauth for Facebook?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm following this tutorial 
http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

for configuring allauth and facebook. Followed it step by step, yet it's still giving me errors.

I'm still new to django and python but from what I can tell I've done everything it tells me to do. Yet I keep getting this error:
Reverse for 'facebook_callback' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Pastebin of the traceback:
http://pastebin.com/SpDLX3iC

Any chance someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py for the allauth part, try this

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'user_birthday', 'publish_stream'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {},
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
    }}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a bit too late, but I fall into same error, and it turns out that I have messed with my `url.py` file and did something wrong to the `allauth` urls. All you have to do is:

```
import allauth.urls

urlpatterns = ...  # your urls

urlpatterns += allauth.urls.urlpatterns  # this is required by allauth to run properly
```